# How do template member functions work in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, static, member

I'm wondering how template member functions work. In particular, when there is an instantiation of the template member function, is the whole class redefined? My confusion comes from the fact that (if I'm right) template classes are not classes in the proper sense. i.e., when instantiated, the compiler creates the definition for a completely new class. The same for template functions. However, classes with a template function seem to be actual classes, so I'm not sure how they could possibly work. Thus, I'm wondering, after instantiating a template member function, what happens with the class definition? Moreover, if I pass a class with a template member function to a template class, can I use the template member function? Could that cause a problem? I tried it once but got an error saying that several functions where defined more that once, although I'm not sure if that was the reason or if there could be an other reason for my error. Is there any further caveat when using static template member functions?

Comment: A specialization of a template, whether class template or function template, is instantiated when first used within a translation unit. Classes can have member templates (both class and function templates), and class templates can, too. Moreover, member functions of class templates are themselves implicitly function templates.

Comment: Note that a template is never instantiated. Only *specializations* of a template can be instantiated.

Comment: Very well, thank you.

Comment: _"template classes are not classes in the proper sense"_ Your confusion comes from calling them "template classes". They are class templates. They are not classes, but instead they are templates for making classes.

Comment: My compiler uses Elven magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class definition remains as it is; all the template function does is generate a family of member functions for that class. As an example:

```
class A {
    public:
        template<typename T> foo (T &t);
}
```

Is not conceptually different from you writing:

```
class A {
    public:
        foo (bool &t);
        foo (int &t);
        foo (double &t);
}
```

...just more convenient. And in the last example, you wouldn't expect a new class to be created for each function would you?

Perhaps the confusion comes from the notion that functions are somehow part of the memory layout of a class; that each function is itself contained in the class, and will be instantiated somewhere in memory whenever an object of the class is created. This notion is incorrect. Functions (templated, global, member, lambda, or otherwise) are never created on the fly or copied around in memory; they are a static and unchanging part of the executable image. The memory layout of the class is not changed by the presence of an extra set of functions, even if those happen to be generated by a template member.

Comment: There would seem to be some strong typing concepts lacking in the example.  Using templates with types makes new types, where your `foo` could have `A* x = new A(true);` or `A* y = new A(123);` with `x` and `y` ending up as the same type

Comment: @infixed 'foo' is not a constructor, so your example code does not apply. The question is specifically about non-template classes with a template member function. No new types are being created.

Answer (score 0):

The template class definition is instantiated when you instantiate a class.  Each member function of it is instantiated when used.  This actually allows you to have member functions that would not work if called when the class is instantiated with some types and not others.  However, you must ensure that the *signature* of the function is either syntactically viable or fails with SFINAE.  It will be looked up during the first phase of parsing.  The body, if the function isn't itself a template, will be checked for name lookup...so dependent names have to be labeled as such via typename.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. There's no such thing as a "template class definition". There's a *class template definition*, but that is never instantiated. Only *specializations* of the template are instantiated. Moreover, a specialization is not instantiated every time it is used, but only the first time it is used (within each translation unit).